# Trying to get the package current version causes errors APPX1706 and APPX1704

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross

I have some troubles with [Windows.ApplicationModel.Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224667) class.

When I try to add the reference to Windows.ApplicationModel or when I'm getting the current package, 17000+ errors appears.

How I try to get the current package :

```
var myPackage = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
```

The kind of error I get :

> error APPX1704:  The file .winmd 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Graphics.Effects.IGraphicsEffect'. The use of spacename Windows is reserved.

Or

> error APPX1706:  The .winmd file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Graphics.Effects.IGraphicsEffect' outside its root namespace 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract'. Make sure that all public types appear under a common root namespace
>   that matches the output file name.

Is there a solution to this problem or a better way to get the current version ?

Comment: Isn't just your SDK or Visual Studio broken? I'm using it the same way and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the issue, it was due to the structure of the solution.

Just like in a Xamarin application, we have a "Core" project that contains the application logic.

We tried to use some Windows app specific namespaces in these shared classes, instead of creating an interface in the Core project and implementing it in the UWP project.

[image: Xamarin code sharing]

Removing the line with the reference to the Windows.ApplicationModel.Package class from the core project and move it to the UWP project resolved the issue.

Sorry for the lack of information on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem I am a bit uncertain, but it is always good idea to reboot (ide, os, etc.), if this is not helping maybe reinstall the SDK, IDE. I know this is not complete answer, it is just from experience.
The second error is saying that your namespaces are not consistent. It means that instead of having Example.Logic, Example.Domain, Example.Utils - you have something like Example.Logic, Test.Domain, Utils (inconsistency of namespaces).

Comment: Well, it worked after the reboot but the same errors came back after I cleaned my solution. I'll try to reinstall the SDK.

Comment: Still didn't work, but I found a way to do the trick by creating a static variable in my App.xaml.cs (where the using of Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation causes no trouble).